DDD EventSourcing ValueObject with multiple languages support
There is an application, written on .net, written with DDD, CQRS+EventSourcing. There is a requirement - add translations to some value objects. How to implement such feature?
e.g.
There is Aggregate product and events:
    public class ProductId
    {
        public long Id {get;set;}
    }
    public class ProductDescription
    {
        public string Description {get;set;}
    }
    public class ProductName
    {
        public string Name{get;set;}
    }
    public class ProductAggregate
    {
        public ProductId {get;set;}
        public ProductDescription Description{get;set;}
        public ProductName Name{get;set;}
        public ProductPrice {get;set;} // no need to have translation for this field while
        ...
    }
    public class DescriptionUpdatedEvent
    {
        ProductId Id{ get;set;}
        PeoductDescription Description {get;set;}
    }

There should be ability to have multiple languages support for some properties of some aggregates. For example, when user is working with UI with Eng language he should see "Product Description" when user switches language in UI to Fr he should see "Description du produit". The question is not like how to translate UI, it's more about how to add translations to data.
My ideas:

Add kind of duplicate field for each field which needs to be translated. It can be dictionary where key is language ("en","fr" etc.)

    public class ProductAggregate
    {
        public ProductId {get;set;}
        public ProductDescription Description{get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,ProductDescription> DescriptionTranslations{get;set;}
    
        public ProductName Name{get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,ProductName> NameTranslations{get;set;}
        ...
    }
    public class DescriptionTrnslationUpdated // new event should be added
    {
        ProductId Id{ get;set;}
        string Language {get;set;} // can be 'en','fr' etc.
        ProductDescription {get;set;}
    }

Looks like it it the simplest approach, only 1 event should be added for each field. The only one problem i see here - we mix Entity with it's translation, and it doubles the size of aggregate

Add such dictionary into ValueObject

    public class ProductDescription
    {
        public string Description {get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,ProductDescription> Translations{get;set;}
    }
    public class DescriptionTrnslationUpdated // new event should be added
    {
        ProductId Id{ get;set;}
        string Language {get;set;} // can be 'en','fr' etc.
        ProductDescription {get;set;}
    }
    public class DescriptionUpdatedEvent2 // since VO modified, old event will be broken and we need to convert old event to new type or create new type and use it
    {
        ProductId Id{ get;set;}
        PeoductDescription Description {get;set;}
    }

This approach looks wired.

Add new aggregate for each language we need to support, which will contain only fields that need to be translated. This aggregate should have probably the same key as previous, so when you need to add translation to Product-1, you know id of translation aggregate it will be ProductFr-1:

    public class ProductFrAggregate
    {
        public ProductId {get;set;}
        public ProductDescription Description{get;set;}
        public ProductName Name{get;set;}
        ...
    }
    public class DescriptionFrUpdated // new event should be added 
    {
        ProductFrId {get;set}
        string Language {get;set;} // can be 'en','fr' etc.
        ProductDescription {get;set;}
    }
    public class DescriptionEnUpdated // new event should be added 
    {
        ProductFrId {get;set}
        string Language {get;set;} // can be 'en','fr' etc.
        ProductDescription {get;set;}
    }

Also simple, bu we should add a lot of Event types, 1 event for each language

Add new aggregate for all languages we need to support, which will contain translations for all fields that need to be translated. This aggregate should have probably the same key as previous, so when you need to add translation to Product-1, you know id of translation aggregate it will be ProductTranslations-1:

    public class ProductTranslationsAggregate
    {
        public ProductTranslationId {get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,ProductDescription> DescriptionTranslations{get;set;}
        public Dictionary<string,ProductName> NameTranslations{get;set;}
        ...
    }
    public class DescriptionTranslationUpdated // new event should be added 
    {
        ProductTranslationId {get;set}
        string Language {get;set;} // can be 'en','fr' etc.
        ProductDescription {get;set;}
    }
    public class NameTranslationUpdated // new event should be added 
    {
        ProductTranslationId {get;set}
        string Language {get;set;} // can be 'en','fr' etc.
        ProductDescription {get;set;}

Looks like it simple like the first one, and not many event types should be added. But since we will work with 2 aggregates, each one will have it's consistency. And it's not clear how to work with it. What if product will be deleted? or there be some logic - kinda "if price changed, description should be updated" it become difficult to manage such situations between 2 aggregates
UPDATE
Found this articles, they are answering to the same questions but for  CRUD, it may be useful:
https://vertabelo.com/blog/multi-language-database-design/
https://medium.com/kocsistem/what-is-the-best-database-design-for-multi-language-data-b21982dd7265

I don't think you are going to find an authoritative answer to this question.
But speaking non authoritatively...
Most of your code probably doesn't care where the translations come from; the code just wants to know what value to use.  For instance, if you were generating a HTML representation of a catalog, we'd probably have a product identifier, and a language code, and a timestamp, and we'd pass those to some black box to get the text we need (possibly wrapped in a data structure with other interesting information).
In other words, the collection of translations, and the policies that determine which translations are used in which circumstances are probably reference data.  In the most naive version, we're just using whatever value the translator last wrote to the database.
If translations, and translation policy, were a key differentiator in your work, then you might have a bunch of aggregates that assist in the process of creating/maintaining translations.  So you'd sit down with your translations "domain expert", and figure out what the processes are, and how autonomation might provide value.
(Alex sends us a new product description, in English.  So first, we identify which translations we need to prepare in advance, here's how we determine that.... Then, for each translation, we submit a request to google translate, to get a machine translation.  Under these conditions, that translation is "good enough", and we'll just use it; under other conditions, we send google's suggestion to Pat and Charlie, who will make improvements, then send that text to Kim for final approval....)
But if you aren't doing anything more that copying information provided to you by translators, then you're probably a database, not a domain model, and getting yourself entangled in a bunch of "aggregate" ceremony is a waste of time and resources.
